# Split a string with a space in Java, when a space occurs?

Tags: java, csv, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to extract data from a CSV file, in which I have the following example CSV

```
timestamp, Column1,column2,column3
2019-05-07 19:17:23,x,y,z
2019-03-30 19:41:33,a,b,c
etc.
```

currently, my code is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[]args){
        String blah = "file.csv";
        File file = new File(blah);
        try{
            Scanner iterate = new Scanner(file);
            iterate.next(); //skips the first line
            while(iterate.hasNext()){
                String data = iterate.next();
                String[] values = data.split(",");
                Float nbr = Float.parseFloat(values[2]);
                System.out.println(nbr);
            }

            iterate.close();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

However, my code is giving me an error

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 is out of bounds for length 3
```

My theory here is the split is the problem here. As there is no comma, my program thinks that the array ends with only the first element since there's no comma on the first element (I've tested it with the timestamp column and it seems to work, however, I want to print the values in column 3)

How do I use the split function to get the column1, column2, and column3 values?

Comment: How about put an `if (values.length > 2)` check before the print to prevent the error? Or run your code in a debugger to see what the line with the issue is?

Comment: Also, I think you want `.nextLine()` and `.hasNextLine()`, otherwise, you're reading up to the spaces or before a line-end character

Comment: Your code is not working as you mentioned,  running as you mentioned is not getting the date, just the time, as it was mentioned in an early comment (use ```.nextLine()```. Also is not clear what is the intent of ```Float nbr = Float.parseFloat(values[2]);``` please clarify

Comment: I want column3 to be a float value for use in a later operation. At the moment, I am still debugging this by using print statements, so the parsefloat is relatively irrelevant at the moment.

Comment: If this is not homework, do not reinvent the wheel: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/index.html. Anyway, your example column  is a character. Probably you are giving a float with a comma as decimal separator (?).

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a homework assignment. In the real world, I would definitely be using libraries such as Commons CSV.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;    
import java.util.*;     
import java.io.*;  
public class Sample  
{  
public static void main(String[] args)   
{  
String line = "";  
String splitBy = ",";  
try   
{  int i=0;
String file="blah.csv";   
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));    
int iteration=0;   
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)   //returns a Boolean value  
{  if(iteration < 1) {  
  iteration++;     
  continue;}   //skips the first line
String[] stu = line.split(splitBy);    
String time=stu[3];   
System.out.println(time);   
 }   
}    
catch (IOException e)      
{     
 e.printStackTrace();    
 }} }
```

Try this way by using BufferedReader
Input:

```
timestamp, Column1,column2,column3    
2019-05-07 19:17:23,x,y,z    
2019-03-30 19:41:33,a,b,c    
2019-05-07 19:17:23,x,y,a    
2019-03-30 19:41:33,a,b,f    
2019-05-07 19:17:23,x,y,x    
2019-03-30 19:41:33,a,b,y
```

Output for this above code is:

```
z   
c   
a   
f
x
y
```

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

1. Use `Scanner#nextLine` and `Scanner#hasNextLine`.
2. Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement.
3. Since lines have either whitespace or a comma as the delimiter, use the regex pattern, `\s+|,` as the parameter to the `split` method. The regex pattern, `\s+|,` means one or more whitespace characters or a comma. Alternatively, you can use `[\s+,]` as the regex pattern.

**Demo:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String blah = "file.csv";
        File file = new File(blah);
        try (Scanner iterate = new Scanner(file)) {
            iterate.nextLine(); // skips the first line
            while (iterate.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = iterate.nextLine();
                String[] values = line.split("[\\s+,]");
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[2019-05-07, 19:17:23, x, y, z]
[2019-03-30, 19:41:33, a, b, c]
```